# Create an auto_increment column based on a group in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm quite new to SQL and databases.

I'm trying to make a preference table of an user.
The fields will be `user_id`, `pref_no`, `prg_code`.

Now if I create the table making `pref_no` `auto_increment` then it will automatically increase irrespective of the `user_id`.

So, my question is - Is there a way to define the table in such a way that it will be `auto_incremented` taking `user_id` into account or I have to explicitly find the last `pref_no` that has occurred for an user and then increment it by 1 before insertion?

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What would you want to happen if you already have a record with preferences for a specific user_id? Should it update the old record? If so, you have to perform a check for the user_id, if it exists, perform an `UPDATE`, and if it does not exist, you do the `INSERT`.

Comment: What you're after works with `MyISAM` engine but that one is quite dated and shouldn't really be used any more. Also, the problem you have isn't solved by using `auto_increment`. `auto_increment` has only one job, and it isn't to produce sequential numbers but unique numbers within concurrent environment and it does it by increasing a counter (so you get infinite possibilities, thus you can truly uniquely identify a record). What you're after is a counter distinguished by `user_id`. You can implement it using triggers.

Comment: @SchmitzIT. No. What I mean is like you are new and you give `Ben 10` as your program. Then the table will have `SchmitzIT` `1` `Ben 10`. Then you give `Power Rangers`, then `SchmitzIT` `2` `Power Rangers` will be added. The `pref_no` increases as you add more programs. Hope I made myself clear.

Comment: @Mjh Thanks! I have something - `triggers`. That makes sense. Let me do some research. :)

Comment: before insertion select the max(pref_no) and with that max(pref_no)+1 insert your new record..I think it will serve your purpose

Comment: No problem, it's nice to see someone willing to do their research and not ask for copy/paste code :) good luck!

Comment: @Mjh I did it finally and has posted an answer based on what I did. However I used procedure to do it. Thanks for the help. :)

Comment: @Fahmina  I did it finally and has posted an answer based on what I did. Thanks for the help. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following what `Mjh` and `Fahmina` suggested, we can create a  procedure for the insertion.

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE test(IN u_id INT(7), p_code INT(5))
    BEGIN
        SELECT @pno:= MAX(pref_no) FROM temp_choice WHERE user_id = u_id; 
        IF @pno IS NULL THEN
            SET @pno = 1;
        ELSE
            SET @pno = @pno + 1;
        END IF;
        INSERT INTO temp_choice VALUES (u_id, @pno, p_code);
     END //
DELIMITER ;
```

Now we can easily insert data by using

```
CALL test(1234567, 10101);
```

Answer (score 0):

To manage user's preference, you don't need `user_id` to be auto_incremented in this table, but `pref_no` has to be.

`user_id` will just be a refence (or foreign key in sql) to your user table (where `user_id` should be auto_incremented).

And to request preference for a given user your request would be :

`SELECT * FROM [user table] INNER JOIN [pref table] ON ([user table].user_id = [pref table].user_id) WHERE [user table].user_id = ?`

(replace '?' by the user_id you want)

Comment: Why are you decomposing the table?

Comment: because user might just stock user's data (something like a login, a password, an email) and a pref table should just handle preferences.
Basically your structure will depends on those questions : 
Do my users will have one preference or many ? Does a preference will be available for only one user or many ?

Comment: that is what i posted originally, user_id and pref_no in a table. To materialize what you are saying I have to make a preference table for individual user, which is an overhead.